# Unable to add spinner items without XML

Tags: android, android-spinner

The code is working fine in Main activity. How to extend this spinner class to all the activities in my project?

The items of spinner are only visible if I add spinner entries in XML
Moreover, There is no call to onItemSelected. I have followed every tutorial possible But couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:entries="@array/MenuItems" />
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:entries="@array/MenuItems" />
```

No item is added programmatically.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MenuItems));
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

My activity_main is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.supreetkaur.pocbeacon.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:elevation="4dp"

          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" >


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:entries="@array/MenuItems" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am a beginner in Android Development. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Try removing `android:entries="@array/MenuItems"` stay with the code!

Comment: It doesn't show any item at all after removing it. That's what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks